# How to add an h2 into a MeanMeanu container

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

Im working on a website that uses the meanmenu, and Ive been struggling for two days on how to get a title to appear inside the mean menu container.

heres my html for the menu:

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-8 col-sm-4">
                    <h2>Title Text</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 hidden-xs">
                    <div class="main-menu float-right">
                        <nav>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="active"><a href="#banner">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#features">What We Do</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#screenshots">Our Work</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#support">Contact Us</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="hidden-sm hidden-lg hidden-md col-sm-2">
                    <div class="mobile-menu">
                        <nav>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="active"><a href="#banner">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
                                <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="#features">What We Do</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#screenshots">Our Work</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#support">Contact Us</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Heres how it looks expanded:
[image]
Collapsed I can't figure out how to get it to stay inline:
[image]

I've seen a few posts on similar issues but nothing has worked for me. Im wondering if anyone has done this before?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you use bootstrap classes not in a right manner

This should works (hope so, because you hide .css from us :) )

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-8 col-lg-4">
                <h2>Title Text</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="visible-xs col-xs-6">
                <div class="mobile-menu">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe cuz u didnt set col-xs-* grids for your Title Text ( hence its taking 12 columns) try that and if possible please post a jsfiddle :)